# How can I "push" a UIViewController from FlutterViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, flutter

I want to "push" a new native view (Activity as in Android & UIViewController as in iOS) upon our Flutter view, and after that new native view is completed/finished, make screen come back to our Flutter view.

I can do this in Android.
But I'm very new to iOS, when I try to do this in `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m`:

```
  SwiftViewController *swiftViewController = [controller.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SwiftViewController"];
  [(FlutterViewController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:swiftViewController animated:YES];
```

It gives error:

> No visible @interface for "FlutterViewController" declared the selector 'pushViewController:animated'

So how to do it in iOS? Thanks

Comment: Beautiful. However I had to work around swift programming to achieve similar result. Also, I had to use my storyboard ID to get my native controller.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to embed FlutterViewController in container [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) programmatically or in storyboard, then you will be able to push your next controller.

Here is example how to embed programmatically:

```c
@interface AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

  UIViewController *flutterViewController = [[FlutterViewController alloc] init];
  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:flutterViewController];
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return true;
}

- (void)pushExample {
  UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
}

@end
```

When needed(e.g. button tapped) invoke `pushExample`. 
Also you can check "storyboard" way in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbI0dR1Msu4)

Comment: Thanks for the help, since I am still struggly learning the black magic of iOS, can I ask for  example code of what you describes, thanks bro

Comment: problem solved, you can find my example code here https://github.com/EasonPai/flutter_pushpop_native_view

Comment: Thank Youuuuuuuuu @"Eason PI"(and also @"German Saprykin")!!!    \o/

Answer (score 6):

In Swift, We can open native iOS viewController from a flutter action event using the method channel,

- **In flutter**, you need to add the following lines to trigger the native iOS method. Add these lines in your action method

```
var platform = const MethodChannel('com.nativeActivity/iosChannel');
final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('StartNativeIOS');
```

- **In iOS**, add the following lines in the AppDelegate application method

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController

let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.nativeActivity/iosChannel", binaryMessenger:controller.binaryMessenger)

methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
  (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        
  if call.method == "StartNativeIOS" {
    let mainVC = MainViewController() // Your viewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
  } else {
    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    return
  }
})
```

It will work! cheers

**Note:** But there is no going back to the flutter view.

So here is the proper way of doing it.
[Flutter Navigation Using Coordinator Pattern](https://medium.com/@cosinus84/flutter-view-controller-used-in-ios-app-using-coordinator-pattern-8896339d64ba)

Answer (score 4):

`pushViewController` only works when your controller is a part of `navigation stack`, i.e. if your `FlutterViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, then you can `push` another controller from it like this:

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(swiftViewController, animated: true)
```

**Second option is**: If `FlutterViewController` is not embedded in `UINavigationController`, you can simply `present` another controller from it like this:

```
    self.present(swiftViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift, We can open native iOS viewController from a flutter action event using the method channel,
In flutter, you need to add the following lines to trigger the native iOS method. Add these lines in your action method

```
var platform = const MethodChannel('navigation');
final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('IOS');
```

In iOS, add the following lines in the AppDelegate application method.

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "navigation", binaryMessenger:controller.binaryMessenger)
navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> 
    Void in
if call.method == "IOS" {
      let vc = "Your viewController"(nibName: "Your 
      viewController", bundle: nil)
      navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: 
     false)
} else {
         result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
         return
}
})
```

Native view controller back button action.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could have a look at the [webview](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) plugin. Similar to your description they start a new Activity or UIViewController. You wont need to start a webview, obviously.

Comment: awesome, your are right, webview plugin definitely have the same flow I want and can be taken as a complete example, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-4a-add-an-ios-platform-specific-implementation-using-objective-c)

Widget with a button. Tap on button should push rely message to push a view controller to the iOS app.

```
class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/navigation_channel');

  Future<void> _pushOnNative() async {
    try {
      Map parameters = Map();
      parameters["title"] = "Contact Details";
      parameters["name"] = "Bang Operator";
      parameters["so_profile_exists"] = true;
      await platform.invokeMethod('push',[parameters]);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to communicate level: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: _pushOnNative,
          child: Text('Push Me'),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

On iOS app side,
We need to observe the channel `samples.flutter.dev/navigation_channel` for method 'push'.
We can also pass arguments from flutter side, in this example we pass a Map(Dart) that is received as NSDictionary(Obj-C)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

  FlutterViewController *controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [self setupNavigationChannelCallbacksOnMessenger:controller
                           forNavigationController:navigationController];


  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)setupNavigationChannelCallbacksOnMessenger:(id<FlutterBinaryMessenger>)messenger
                           forNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
  FlutterMethodChannel* pushChannel = [FlutterMethodChannel
                                       methodChannelWithName:@"samples.flutter.dev/navigation_channel"
                                       binaryMessenger:messenger];

  [pushChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall* call, FlutterResult result) {
    if ([call.method isEqualToString:@"push"] && [self getDictionaryFromArguments:call.arguments]) {
      NSDictionary *parameters = [self getDictionaryFromArguments:call.arguments];
      [self pushContactScreenWithInfo:parameters onNaivgationController:navigationController];
      result(@(true));
    } else {
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
    }
  }];
}

- (NSDictionary *)getDictionaryFromArguments:(id)arguments {
  if (![arguments isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    return nil;
  }
  NSArray *argumentsArray = (NSArray *)arguments;
  if (argumentsArray.firstObject == nil || ![argumentsArray.firstObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    return nil;
  }
  return (NSDictionary *)argumentsArray.firstObject;
}

- (void)pushContactScreenWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
          onNaivgationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationContorller {
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  ContactViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactViewController"];
  [navigationContorller pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  [controller view];
  [controller configureWithInfo:info];
}
```

Comment: How can I go back to flutter screen. I tried with pop ViewController in native ios and then it go back to splash screen of the flutter app. 
I want like from flutter screen where I tapped button and  pushed the view controller that should only pop and show the same flutter screen where my button placed
How can i do this please help